# Azure Container Instance not running all steps in Dockerfile

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, python-poetry, azure-container-instances

I've got a Docker container I'm trying to deploy on Azure, but when I do it looks like it doesn't run all the steps in the Dockerfile. The last part of my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
RUN cd /import/project/import && \
git checkout docker-image && \
poetry install && \
poetry run pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./env-info/* /import

CMD /import/start-scheduler
```

This container runs locally just fine, but when I deploy it in Azure I get:

```
Creating virtualenv project-import-g_UpH0zE-py3.9 in /acb/home/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/import/project/import/project.py", line 16, in <module>
    import click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'
```

Weirdly, if I change it to the following and execute all the code which is supposed to be executed in the run step, it works fine:

```
RUN cd /import/project/import && \
git checkout docker-image && \
poetry install && \
poetry run pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./env-info/* /import

CMD cd /import/project/import && git checkout docker-image && poetry install && poetry run pip install -r requirements.txt && /import/start-scheduler
```

What's going on?

Comment: How are you running the container?  (Is there any sort of volume mount that might hide part of the image?)  What is in the `env-info` directory, and might that conflict with the other image content?

Comment: The other obvious difference is that the current directory is different in the two cases; `RUN cd ...` doesn't persist beyond the current step.  Perhaps it would help to change the `WORKDIR` before running these commands?

Comment: There's no local volume mounts. And it runs cd /import/project/import at the start of each of them.

The issue seems to be related to `poetry` — `poetry` creates a virtual environment to run in, and it looks like the shell doesn't match when I run in the cloud, but does when I run locally?

Comment: Your first Dockerfile doesn't change the `WORKDIR` or otherwise `cd` inside the `CMD`, which is where I suspect it might be in the wrong directory.

Comment: That script is literally `cd /import/project/import python -m import scheduler` and it does run in my local, which it shouldn't if the directories were wrong.